# Comment choisir entre le subjonctif et l'indicatif ?

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, indicatif

Que faut-il utiliser ici ? Le subjonctif ou l'indicatif présent ? Et comment choisir entre les deux ?

> Le moins qu’on **puisse/peut** dire est que la crise ne laisse
>   personne indifférent

En espagnol, par exemple, ils utilisent le présent de l'indicatif.

Comment: Question choix, le moins qu'on *puisse* dire, c'est qu'on en fait souvent le moins qu'on *peut*... Reste que ceci est la preuve qu'entre subjonctif et indicatif, il y a bien un choix à faire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La remarque est troublante et très juste, je n'avais pas envisagé cette forme... je suis très intéressé par l'analyse grammaticale qui pourrait l'expliquer.

Comment: @Romain: L'explication n'est pas à chercher dans une analyse grammaticale, elle ne peut venir que d'une analyse sémantique. Peut-être que les linguistes ont des outils pour ça. Perso je me rends compte que dans des cas comme celui-là, je ne sais choisir entre indicatif et subjonctif que grâce à l'expérience, parce je ne saurais pas l'expliquer clairement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est a priori le subjonctif qui semble le plus naturel à l'oreille (**le moins qu'on puisse dire**). Pour la justesse de la règle grammaticale, je laisse nos spécialistes donner un réponse circonstanciée.

En tout cas, je ne pense pas avoir jamais entendu *le moins qu'on peut dire*...

---

Voir éventuellement aussi [ce nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le%20moins%20qu%27on%20peut,le%20moins%20qu%27on%20puisse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=). Cela ne remplace pas l'explication grammaticale idoine, mais c'est pour se donner une idée des fréquences d'usage.

Comment: Merci, parfait :)

Answer (score 2):

L'usage me semble varier mais le subjonctif dominer néanmoins nettement.  Pour moi, on se trouve dans le cas décrit par Grevisse, *le bon usage*,

> Le subjonctif se met [dans la proposition relative] dans les cas suivants.
>
> [...]
>
> 2° Ordinairement, quand l'antécédent contient un superlatif relatif ou un adjectif de sens analogue (*seul*, *premier*, *dernier*, *principal*, *unique*, etc.)

Et comme souvent, il cite plus d'exemples chez les bons auteurs ne suivant pas la règle que d'exemples la suivant.

Comment: Merci à toi aussi, si je pourrais j'accepterais tous les deux :)