# Subjunctive with deuxième, troisième, etc

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

I've read that the subjunctive is often used with the expression *le premier*. For example:

> Cendrillon était le premier conte de Disney que j'**aie** jamais lu.

Is it still used when the expression is *le deuxième*, *le troisième*, etc.?

> Cendrillon était le deuxième conte de Disney que j'**aie**/**ai** jamais lu.

Comment: Answer is [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4598/358).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence:

> Cendrillon **était** le premier conte de Disney que **j'aie** jamais lu.

is odd. The first Disney tale you ever read will stay it forever so the sentence can simply be:

> Cendrillon **est** le premier conte de Disney que **j'aie** jamais lu.

If you want to keep the imperfect, to comply with the sequence of tenses the sentence should rather be:

> Cendrillon **était** le premier conte de Disney que **j'avais** jamais lu.

Note that neither ***j'ai jamais lu*** nor ***j'avais jamais lu*** are negative here. *Jamais* is used in its positive meaning (ever).

Then if you want to talk about the second or the third tale, I would discard *jamais* as it is almost always used in this construction to refer to something unique, and the second and subsequent tales are "less unique" than the first one.

The TLFi states in the [jamais entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais) I.− F.- 1.-:

> *Le référent de l'antécédent est repéré comme unique (par rapport à un ensemble de référence)*

I would then suggest:

> Blanche-Neige **était** le deuxième conte de Disney **que j'avais lu**.
>
> Blanche-Neige **est** le deuxième conte de Disney **que j'ai lu**.

Comment: Shouldn't the last sentence have *aie* instead of *ai*? The link provided by Laure says "Ordinairement, quand l'antécédent contient un superlatif relatif ou un adjectif de sens analogue", and I think "deuxième" is "un adjectif de sens analogue".

Comment: I wouldn't use the subjunctive for the same reason I wouldn't use *jamais*. In Laure's link, only superlatives and similar are present *(seul, premier, dernier, principal, unique, etc.)*. *Premier* is an adjective *de sens analogue à un superlatif* but *deuxième* is not  because it doesn't represent an extremity.

Answer (score 0):

La négation n'est pas utile dans ce cas-ci. 
Votre exemple donnerait alors :

> Cendrillon était le premier conte Disney que j'aie lu

Cela fonctionnera alors avec **le deuxième, le troisième...**

Le subjonctif peut être utilisé dans ce cas-là

Comment: La question porte sur l'utilisation du subjonctif, pas sur la négation.

Comment: Désolé, j'avais mal lu le question, Je vais y répondre

Comment: D'autant plus qu'il n'y a pas de négation.